# when I join my clothing mesh to my armature, the mesh deforms

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm new to blender and I'm making a simple rigged character but whenever I try to join my clothing mesh to the armature, the mesh becomes deformed.[image]

The armature still moves the mesh in pose mode, but I don't know how to fix this mesh deformity. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: first apply the scale and rotation of the cloth and armature, also make sure that the normals are correctly flipped, then parent again. If it still doesn't work please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots sry, could you explain what you mean? I didn't get what you meant.

Comment: Please provide the file it will be easier, upload the file then copy paste the URL it will generate: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: The file exceeds the 24mb capacity of pasteall. Is there any other way I can send it to you?

Comment: send it to yourself with wetransfer and share the link here

Comment: Here you go, https://we.tl/t-fgIwOuiBYk

Comment: also, you are not supposed to rig nor animate with the metarig, You are supposed to use the metarig to generate Rigify's full rig.

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to parent your costume while your armature was not in rest pose.

Apply the scale of your objects and armature, also apply the rotation of your costume. Bring back your armature to its reset pose in *Pose* mode with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>. Once done, put the costume at the same position as the armature. As you'll see there's still a problem, your armature default pose it a T pose, not your costume, so you need to align the costume shape:

[image]

You could do it this way: Duplicate the armature, in *Edit* mode align the bones with the costume shape, parent the costume to this second armature, move the armature to a T pose, apply the armature, now your costume has a T pose as well, you can parent it to the first armature.